# How to use tzutc()

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

What am I missing, how do I get this function to work?

```
import dateutil.parser
import datetime

my_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 000000, tzinfo=tzutc())

print(my_date)
```

---

Gives me the error:

```
NameError: name 'tzutc' is not defined
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You did not import it:

```
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
```