# How to convert from UTC to tzutc() timezone?

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a naive timestamp which I need to convert to `tzutc()` timedate in order to calculate time delta.

I converted string to Date using

```
pd.Timestamp(x)
```

Then converted it to UTC using

```
pytz.utc.localize(x)
```

and got:

```
Timestamp('2019-01-09 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Problem is that the date I need to compare it to is

```
Timestamp('2018-06-07 18:13:53+0000', tz='tzutc()')
```

When comparing them I get

```
TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625803/how-to-use-tzutc/44625872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the timestamp to a datetime and back using the methods seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825349/converting-between-datetime-and-pandas-timestamp-objects).

Here is a method for converting a datetime from local time to UTC using pytz:

```
def LocalToUTC(dt):
    # Converts the local time to UTC

    localtz = get_localzone()

    if dt.tzinfo is None:
        localdt = localtz.localize(dt)
    else:
        localdt = dt.replace(tzinfo=localtz)

    utcdt = localdt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    return utcdt
```

Similarly here is a method for converting any timezone to UTC:

```
def TimezoneToUTC(dt, timezonestring):
    # Converts from a given timezone to UTC using the timezonestring
    # Example timezone string: 'Europe/Paris' OR 'America/New_York'

    fromtz = pytz.timezone(timezonestring)

    if dt.tzinfo is None:
        localdt = fromtz.localize(dt)
    else:
        localdt = dt.replace(tzinfo=fromtz)

    utcdt = localdt.astimezone(pytz.UTC)
    return utcdt
```

For a list of all timezone strings use:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> 
>>> for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
...     print tz
```

Comment: Thank you @iridium237. Eventually thanks to your  link I've devised another solution: I simply defined the time zone of the original date to tzutc

Like this: pd.Timestamp(x,tz=tzutc())
Making both datestamps be in the same timezone.